# How to run a Windows GUI application from a Windows VM on a Docker installed on windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I have installed Docker toolbox and Installed a Windows 7 VM on my Windows 7 Physical Machine.

How can I run a GUI application(Lets say notepad.exe) from this VM?

Additionally is it possible to boot into this Windows VM?